# Word that describes shortening of a single “string”

Tags: single-word-requests

In programming, the word “concatenation” is often used for combining multiple individual strings into one. Is there a reverse of this? For dropping a piece of a string, or number?

For example, in some weather contexts, you’ll still see numbers like 1012.5, but it becomes 125. What is a word that means this “trim” of numbers/characters?

Comment: I can't see how 1012.5 becomes 125. Could we have more examples, please?

Comment: @Andrew Leach in that case it’s just dropping the 10 and removing the decimal, but that’s a bad example I suppose. Really just looking for a word that’s the reverse of concatenation. Could have sworn there was something other than “trim” or “split”

Comment: There is, but please provide better examples so I can be sure that the word I'm thinking of is actually the one for your situation.

Comment: Try *truncation* (verb: *truncate*). Though it has a specific meaning in decimal numbers, if you mean something more general (the opposite of "trim") then it works for you.

Comment: I meant the opposite of *concat*, not *trim*. Durr.

Comment: Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/concatenate), antonyms of *concatenate* include *disconnect, disjoin, disjoint, dissever, disunite, separate, unchain, uncouple, unhitch, unlink,* and *unyoke*. (Or, most colloquially, *split*, as in one of the provided answers.) But, aside from *asking* for the opposite of *concatenate*, nothing you've described actually *means* the opposite of *concatenation*.

Comment: In weather terms I’d call that an ***abbreviation***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you're thinking of ***[truncate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/truncated)*** (dictionary.com) but that generally refers to removing one end of something. It usually wouldn't apply to any shortening that takes place in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion to *split* a string is the opposite.
In modern programming languages you can find a split method to do this job.

For further information you could check the *split* method description of the programming langue *Java*:
[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: *split* typically returns both parts.  *truncate* only returns one part.

Comment: Hi Mikail. The system has flagged your answer for closure as "low-quality because of its length and content." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*, whereas you're offering a personal opinion without anything to support it. You can [edit] your answer to avoid closure - e.g. add a reference for "split" used in this context, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)